# Standard text LCD menu system

Tags: lcd, c

Is there a pattern out there for a simple menu system in C for a text LCD. I find myself re-writing code a lot for handling simple text LCD menus.

I find most systems have a main menu and some sub-menus that when selected allow you to set a parameter with within some minimum and maximum value.

Ideally this menu system could be navigated with 4 simple keys such as enter, cancel, up, and down.

In my application I'm using a 2 line x 16 character text LCD though an ideal solution should be able to be applied to any NxM display.

Comment: Nothing to do with electronic design! Question will be closed.

Comment: I was under the impression programming questions if they applied to embedded systems could be asked here too. Maybe I was wrong...

Comment: I was under similar impression too. Is there an official note about that?

Comment: Only very low-level stuff, according to the FAQ. This question is about the user interface.

Comment: Is there a way to migrate the question instead of just having it closed?

Comment: +1 I would be interested too...I've always hand-brewed them. Are you using a console output or a NxM character display....not that I have an answer for either :) On several embedded 2xN display systems, I've implemented two button interfaces with combining Enter/Cancel and have Next which is a ring buffer and eliminates the need for up/next & down/back.

Comment: @Leon (and everybody else) - I'm not sure where this question lies.   The FAQ does reference low-level stuff, but I think that was in response to questions about embedded Linux and Windows systems that were really just low-spec'ed PCs.  In comparison, I'd call this 'very low-level'.  We need a more precise definition.  I've started [a Meta question](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/852/is-code-specifically-related-to-embedded-systems-on-topic) to discuss this further.

Comment: @mjh2007 - Yes, we can migrate it to stackoverflow if that's where you (and the community) want it.  Please weigh in on the meta question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pattern I use for menu systems in C is something like this:

```
struct menuitem
{
  const char *name; // name to be rendered
  functionPointer handlerFunc; // handler for this leaf node (optionally NULL)
  struct menu *child; // pointer to child submenu (optionally NULL)
};

struct menu
{
  struct menu *parent; // pointer to parent menu
  struct **menuitem; // array of menu items, NULL terminated
};
```

I then declare an array of `menu`s each containing `menuitem`s and pointers to `child` submenus. Up and down moves through the currently selected array of `menuitem`s. Back moves to the `parent` menu and forward/select either moves to a `child` submenu or calls a `handlerFunc` for a leaf node.

Rendering a menu just involves iterating through its items.

The advantage of this scheme is that it's fully data driven, the menu structures can be statically declared in ROM independent of the renderer and handler functions.

Answer (score 2):

Toby's answer is a very good starting point.  The structures mentioned assume that the menus are static and you just navigate through them.

If you want dymanic menus (e.g. displaying certain values, such as temperature, time, etc), then you need to be able to generate that.

One way could be to have register a function to build your string.

```
struct menuitem
{
  const char *name; // name to be rendered
  const char * (*builderFunc)( const char *name );  // callback to generate string, if not null.
  functionPointer handlerFunc; // handler for this leaf node (optionally NULL)
  struct menu *child; // pointer to child submenu (optionally NULL)
};
```